# Open alert on click of button-Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and trying hard to open alert on click of button.Following is the code snippet i am using:

```
<button class="button button-dark" ng-click="showAlert()">Sample Alert</button>
```

in controller.js

```
.controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $q, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
            template: 'It might taste good'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
           console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
        });
    };
})
```

I am have gone through:[First steps with ionic to get popup alert on button tap / click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299891/first-steps-with-ionic-to-get-popup-alert-on-button-tap-click) but,nothing helped.What am i doing wrong?

Also,it gives me following error:

```
Error: $ionicPopup is not defined
$scope.showAlert@http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:20:13
$parseFunctionCall@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21044:15
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53458:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23100:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23199:18
@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53457:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11713:9
triggerMouseEvent@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2863:3
tapClick@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2852:3
tapMouseUp@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2925:5


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

Am I needed something under app.js?

Comment: Normally your controller looks fine, may I see the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1):

this is because you didn't add $ionicPopup in your controller dependencies.
Try replacing your controller with one of the following (preferably first)

**1.**

```
.controller('PopupCtrl', popupCtrl);

popupCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', '$ionicPopup'];

var popupCtrl = function($scope, $timeout, $q, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
            template: 'It might taste good'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
           console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
        });
    };
}
```

or

**2.**

```
.controller('PopupCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', '$ionicPopup', function($scope, $timeout, $q, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.showAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
            template: 'It might taste good'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
           console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
        });
    };
}])
```

i personally use the first syntax in my projects and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `ionic` as a dependency in your app's main module? 
Did you include `ionic.bundle.js` in your index.html? Or are you loading `angular` and `ionic` individually? If yes, try with `ionic.bundle.js`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following plugins:

- org.apache.cordova.console
- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Also make sure you include in your index the following:

```
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check if you've included 'ionic' in your app module:

```
angular.module('surveyApp', ['ionic'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using `ng-controller="PopupCtrl"` in your HTML where your button is placed.